# even with specified formatting and index, error "index has bad entries"

Tags: r, zoo

I am reading in CSV that is derived from daymet data, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pPBDxgkPJG6QtUsSl20Ny8q59kSO7EWLx0oHTuIrrwU/edit?usp=sharing found here, so a row for every day from January 1, 1980 to early July 2019. It works when I just read in the CSV but it will not read as a zoo object. Out of 14,235 rows, there are errors at rows: 60 1520 2980 4440 5900. So its not like its at any regular interval.

It seems like common problems are people not specifying an index, having missing data, or messing up time zones. Every date that I am indexing is unique, no missing data, and no time.

I've tried every iteration of reading in the CSV and zoo

```
h2o.bal.0001 <- read.csv("data/waterbalanceoutputs/daily/CARE0001.csv", header=T)
h2o.bal.0001 <- h2o.bal.0001[,-c(2:4)]#removing any non-essential columns
h2o.bal.0001$date <- as.POSIXct(h2o.bal.0001$date, format="%m/%d/%y")
h2o.bal.0001.zoo <- read.zoo(h2o.bal.0001, FUN=as.POSIXct, format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

```
h2o.bal.0001 <- read.csv("data/waterbalanceoutputs/daily/CARE0001.csv", header=T)
h2o.bal.0001 <- na.omit(h2o.bal.0001)
h2o.bal.0001 <- read.zoo(file=h2o.bal.0001, header=T,
                                 format="%m/%d/%y", index.column=1)
```

```
h2o.bal.0001 <- read.zoo(read.csv(file="data/waterbalanceoutputs/daily/CARE0001.csv", header=T, format="%m/%d/%y", index.column=1))
```

Comment: "derived from" tells us almost nothing. How? What code?

Comment: Its model output from a model that isnt run in R and is working well. I used bad wording, but take it to mean its a long, compete time series